# Can replace Vaadin layout component inside Panel?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Am using Vaadin 7.3.10.

I have added a layout component inside a panel in order that
the layouts shall be scrolled if required.

However when I try to replace the layout component, the new 
component adds to (is shown below) rather than replaces the
existing component - see below for code sample.

How/Can this be done?

n.b. if the layout is not contained inside the panel, the
replacement occurs correctly.
Also, I do not require to use the Navigator for this.

Thank you,
Steve...

```
import com.vaadin.ui.Button;
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;
import com.vaadin.ui.Panel;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button.ClickEvent;

public class NewComponent extends VerticalLayout {

private VerticalLayout mainLayout = new VerticalLayout();
private Panel panel = new Panel();

public NewComponent() {

    mainLayout.addComponent(new Label("Main"));
    mainLayout.setSizeFull();       
    addComponent(mainLayout);

    panel.setWidth("1000px");
    panel.setHeight("500px");       
    panel.setContent(mainLayout);

    Button button = new Button("Click Me");
    button.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            replaceComponent(mainLayout,  new Label("what's wrong?"));
        }
    });

    mainLayout.addComponent(button);    
    addComponent(panel);            
}
}

public class TestUI extends UI {

@WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
@VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = TestUI.class)
public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
}

@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    setContent(new NewComponent());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `replaceComponent` **on** the `mainLayout` and not **with**.

right now it looks like this:

```
<newComponent>
    <panel>
        <mainLayout>
            <labelMain/>
            <clickMeButton/>
        </mainLayout>
    </panel>
</newComponent>
```

then you call `replaceComponent` on newComponent, which will add the label like this

```
<newComponent>
    <panel>
        <mainLayout>
            <labelMain/>
            <clickMeButton/>
        </mainLayout>
    </panel>
    <whatsWrongLabel/>
</newComponent>
```

It **should** look like this:

```
<newComponent>
    <panel>
        <mainLayout>
            <labelMain/>
        </mainLayout>
    </panel>
    <clickMeButton/>
</newComponent>
```

and then `mainLayout.replaceComponent(labelMain, whatsWrongLabel)`.

Answer (score 1):

mainLayout is not in the VerticalLayout, that's why the new component is simply added to it. You have to replace the panel's content.

Change

```
    replaceComponent(mainLayout,  new Label("what's wrong?"));
```

To

```
    panel.setContent(new Label("what's wrong?"));
```